# Remove top divider from viewlist?

Tags: android-listview

I have a list of items. How do I remove top divider from the list ?

I already removed the footer didider by:

```
listView.setFooterDividersEnabled(false);
```

-talx

Answer (score 2):

try to do this

```
listView.setHeaderDividersEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Seems to remove all the dividers for me, I would like to remove the top most one since its causing a double line for me

Comment: yes, setHeaderDividersEnabled(false) on the listView remove only its top divider, such as setFooterDividersEnabled(false) only the footer